# Implementation of adding element to ArrayList and removing element from ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I want to insert a new element into Array List before the position specified by index with add(int i, T t) method in My Array List Class. And also I want to remove all elements from Array List with Clear() method in My Array List Class.

How can I implement this?

My Array List Class:

public class MyArrayList  {

```
private int n=0; //initial size of the array list 
private MyArrayListElement<T> firstElement;//the first element of the array list 
//Gets the element at index i 
private MyArrayListElement<T> getElement(int i){ 
    if(firstElement == null) return null; 
    int c = 0; 
    MyArrayListElement<T> x=firstElement; 
    while(x!=null){ 
        if(c==i) return x; 
        x=x.getNext(); 
        c++; 
    } 
    return null; 
} 
//Gets the element value at index i 
public T get(int i){ 
    MyArrayListElement<T> element = getElement(i); 
    if(element!=null) return element.getValue(); 
    return null; 
} 
//Removes the element at index i 
public void remove(int i){ 
    MyArrayListElement<T> x= getElement(i); 
    if(x==null) return; 
    if(x.getPrevious()!=null){ 
        x.getPrevious().setNext(x.getNext()); 
    } 
    if(x.getNext()!=null){ 
        x.getNext().setPrevious(x.getPrevious()); 
    } 
    if(x==firstElement){ 
        firstElement = x.getNext(); 
    } 
    n--; // decrement the size of the array list 
} 
//Adds a new element to the end 
public void add(T t){ 
    MyArrayListElement<T> element = new MyArrayListElement<T>(t); 
    if(firstElement == null){ 
        firstElement = element; 
    }else{ 
        MyArrayListElement<T> lastElement=getElement(n-1); //Get the last element 
        lastElement.setNext(element); //Add new element to the end 
        element.setPrevious(lastElement);//Update previous element 
    } 
    n++; //increment the size 
} 
//Returns the number of elements in the array list 
public int size(){ 
    return n; 
} 
public String toString(){ 
    String str ="{"; 
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){ 
        str+=get(i); 
        if(i<n-1){ 
            str+=","; 
        } 
    } 
    str+="}"; 
    return str; 
} 

public void add(int index, T t) {

}

public void clear(){

}
```

My Array List Element  Class:

public class MyArrayListElement  {

```
private T value; // This is the data stored in this element 
private MyArrayListElement <T> next; // the next element 
private MyArrayListElement <T> previous; // the previous element 

//Constructor gets an object of type <T> as an argument 
public MyArrayListElement(T t) { 
    value = t; //stores the object in the instance variable "value" 
} 
public void setValue(T val){ 
    value = val; //change the stored object 
} 
public void setNext(MyArrayListElement <T> n){ 
    next = n; //set the link to the next element 
} 
public MyArrayListElement<T> getNext() { 
    return next; //get the next element 
} 
public T getValue(){ 
    return value; //get the data stored in this element 
} 
public MyArrayListElement <T> getPrevious() { 
    return previous; //get the previous element 
} 
public void setPrevious(MyArrayListElement <T> previous) { 
    this.previous = previous; //set the link to the previous element 
}
```

}

Comment: Is this homework? Or why would you want to implement your own ArrayList?

Comment: If you really don't want to do your homework yourself, you can just use any search engine and search for doubly linked list, you will find the algorithm (there's one in wikipedia in pseudo code).

Comment: That's not an array list which, as its name indicates, is backed by an array. It's a linked list.

Comment: First of all - this is a linked list not an array list...But to answer this in short, without much effort (as it sees to be some kind of homework) when setting, you should call getElement with given index and insert new element between `i`'th element and it's `next` (create new element, set it's next to `i`ths next and set the new element as `i`'ths next), deleting a single element will be similar, and clear - you have to traverse through whole collection and null references to prev / next

Comment: It is homework. Yes. However, this part is very tough. I did not asked about all homework. Just need help.

Comment: Then my previous comment should push you in the right direction - Have fun!

Comment: public void add(int index, T t) {
  MyArrayListElement<T> new_element = new MyArrayListElement<T>(t); 
  MyArrayListElement<T> x= getElement(index); 
  new_element.setNext(x.getNext());
  x.setNext(new_element.getNext());
 }

like this?

Answer (score 0):

I will explain you at a conceptual mode...

make a clone of your arraylist that should be empty -> yourArray.`clear()` is the function that you need to do that.

make a loop

add  elements from original arraylist into your clone array until the index that you want to insert.
if index=your target cloneArray.add(yourelement); and also add index element... after that continue loop normaly.

Comment: to have more control for(int i=0;i<yourOriginalArray.size()i++){if(i==index){newArray.add(yournewobject)}newarray.add(youroriginalarray.get(i)))}